# JQuery file input type not being recognised

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand something.  If I do the following

```
 if( $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'application/pdf') {
        errors.push("- Please upload correct document type");
    }
```

It works as it should do...If I dont upload a PDF, I get an error, if I do, I dont get an error.  However, if I change it to the following

```
if(  $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/bmp' ||
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/jpeg' ||
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/pjpeg' ||
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/png' ||
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/tiff' ||
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'application/pdf') 
{
    errors.push("- Please upload one of the valid document types");
}
```

If I upload a PDF or any other file listed there, it still throws the error.  It seems that adding all the extra types seems to make it fail.

Is there any reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use && instead of ||:

```
var ftype = $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type;
if( ftype != 'image/bmp' && 
    ftype != 'image/jpeg' &&
    ftype != 'image/pjpeg' &&
    ftype != 'image/png' &&
    ftype != 'image/tiff' &&
    ftype != 'application/pdf') {
    errors.push("- Please upload one of the valid document types");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at your logic:

> If it is not a bitmap OR if it is not a JPEG

If it **is** a bitmap, then it **isn't** a JPEG and vice versa.

Your condition can never be true.

You want an AND test not an OR test.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AND insteod of OR:

```
if(  $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/bmp' &&
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/jpeg' &&
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/pjpeg' &&
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/png' &&
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/tiff' &&
            $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'application/pdf') 
{
    errors.push("- Please upload one of the valid document types");
}
```